# pr2_dashboard installation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

Once i have problems with PR2, now i need to install the PR2_Dashboard... someone helps me??

another thing, i saw that the installation starts like this:

sudo apt-get  install XXXXXXXXXXX, how can i know what is the package to install, is any list of the packages to install?, where can i get it... is better like this i dont have to ask you everytime...

thank you!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47480/pr2_dashboard-installation/) by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2012-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-pr2-gui
```

The name of the debian package to install is always:

```
ros-<distro>-<stack>
```

Note that underscores are replaced by dashes in the stack name, i.e. the  debian package for the stack pr2_gui is ros-fuerte-pr2-gui.

To find the stack of a package, have a look at the wiki. In your case: http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_dashboard

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2012-11-05**:
thank you, your help is good.... really thanks...